# EXT JS ASP MVC dynamically load form fields from a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

I need to dynamically populate a form from fields in a database using EXT JS forms and ASP.NET MVC and I'm having trouble finding a starting point.

The database includes all of the settings: the field names, the field data types and the original field data. When a menu is clicked on the application's main page, the clicked item's settings should appear on a separate form. The data types include checkboxes, textfields, and possibly combo boxes.

I can easily return all of the settings in Json, but I know the form will need to iterate either with Ext.each or some other method, but I'm having trouble getting my head around this. I've also thought about using an Ext reusable type as a template that accepts Json data from the database to determine the field name, type and content.

something like this:

```
TextSettings = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
    layout: 'column',
    autoHeight: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                style: 'float:left;clear:left;',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        text: 'Setting Name',
                        style: 'display:block;',
                        ref: '../../../NameLabel'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        text: 'Setting description',
                        style: 'display:block;font-style:italic;',
                        ref: '../../../DescriptionLabel'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                style: 'float:right;clear:right;',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        width: 300,
                        ref: '../../../SettingEdit'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        TextSettings.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

Does this look like a crash course?

Has anyone else done something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across this Ajax function online (probably the Sencha forums) and it seems to be working.

```
 var ajax = Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/Controller/Items',
        method: 'get',
        success: function (response) {
            response = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            //form.add(Ext.decode(response.responseText).data);
            for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                form.add({
                    xtype: response.data[i].xtype,
                    fieldLabel: response.data[i].text,
                    name: response.data[i].name,
                    value: response.data[i].value,
                    style: response.data[i].style,
                    items: response.data[i].items,
                    width: response.data[i].width
                });
            }
            form.doLayout();
        }
    });
```

With the following Json output:

```
{success: true, data: [{xtype: 'label', text: 'Report', style: 'display:block', ref: '../../../Displaylabel' },{xtype: 'label', text: \"Report Text\", style: 'display:block;font-style:italic;', ref: '../../../DescriptionLabel'},{xtype: \"textfield\", width: 300, ref: \"../../../SettingEdit\", value: \"A comment... for YOU!!!\"}, {xtype: 'checkbox', text: 'Check it for fun'}]}
```

Still more work to go, but this is at least giving me dynamic text fields.